# ToolStripButton does not contain a definition for 'Transparent'

Tags: c#, winforms

I get the following error:

> Error 4   'System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripButton' does not contain a definition for 'Transparent' and no extension method 'Transparent' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripButton' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) C:\Users\E1\Desktop\text editor\Editor\Editor\Form1.cs  321 34  Editor

I'm trying to implement the following code:

```
protected void PaintTransparentBackground(Graphics graphics, Rectangle clipRect)
{
  graphics.Clear(Color.Transparent);
  if ((this.Parent != null))
  {
    clipRect.Offset(this.Location);
    PaintEventArgs e = new PaintEventArgs(graphics, clipRect);
    GraphicsState state = graphics.Save();
    graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighSpeed;
    try
    {
      graphics.TranslateTransform((float)-this.Location.X, (float)-this.Location.Y);
      this.InvokePaintBackground(this.Parent, e);
      this.InvokePaint(this.Parent, e);
    }
    finally
    {
      graphics.Restore(state);
      clipRect.Offset(-this.Location.X, -this.Location.Y);
    }
  }
}
```

It says the toolstrip button doesn't contain that definition. I want to do it for tabs, but it doesn't seem to work. Never experienced such an problem.

Any hints?

Comment: Which line does the error fall on?

Comment: which line is giving error?

Comment: I guess the code having error has not been posted yet.

Comment: @DGibbs Line 4, in `Color.Transparent`

Comment: the code has the line that throws the error.. `TRANSPARENT` is the key.. so `Color.Transparent` would be my educated guess..

Comment: what is the name of your class?

Comment: @erm_durr you might name your `ToolStripButton` `Color`? That has the same name with the `Color` structure, and the ToolStripButton variable is used instead (not `Color` structure).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try adding System.Drawing in front of Color.Transparent.  My guess is that you have a property defined as Color in your form class.

```
graphics.Clear(System.Drawing.Color.Transparent);
```

If this does the trick, then I suggest you rename your Color property to something more specific like ColorButton or whatever.

Comment: It solved my problem, but I have two errors: `Error 4 The type or namespace name 'GraphicsState' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) C:\Users\E1\Desktop\text editor\Editor\Editor\Form1.cs 326 17 Editor` and `Error 5 The name 'SmoothingMode' does not exist in the current context C:\Users\E1\Desktop\text editor\Editor\Editor\Form1.cs 327 42 Editor
`

Comment: Completely different problem now, but try adding "using System.Drawing.Drawing2D" to the top of your file.